# closing an object type in ocaml

Tags: inheritance, ocaml, self-type

For my Qt5 bindings I have a inheritance tree of ocaml classes that take a c++ object as parameter. So this works along the inheritance chain the base class has a `method obj` returning an 'a t where 'a is the self type. The problem now is that the users needs to be able to inherit my ocaml classes so I have to close the type or otherwise remove or hide the `method obj` and the `obj` parameter. The user has no way to create a derived c++ object.

```
type 'a t (* type of the c++ objects *)

(* ocaml wrapper around the c++ object *)
class foo (obj : 'a t) = object(self:'a)
  method obj = obj
  method foo = "foo"
end

(* external function returning c++ object *)
let make_foo_t () = ((Obj.magic 0) : foo t)

(* way for the user to create a foo *)
let make () = new foo (make_foo_t ())

(* class the user can derive from hiding the c++ object *)
class bar = object
  inherit foo (make_foo_t ())
  method bar = "bar"
end

(* user *)
let x = new bar;;

class derived_bar = object
    inherit bar
    method dervived_bar = "derived_bar"
end
```

The problem is I can't get the class bar to work. Whatever I do ocaml complains about "Self type cannot be unified with a closed object type" or "Self type cannot escape its class".

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying and several starts from scratch I found a solution that works even if it isn't pretty. Still looking for something better:

```
module type Make = sig
  val stub : unit -> #foo t
end

class bar () =
  let obj =
    let module E = (val (module struct
      external stub : unit -> #foo t = "stub"
    end) : Make)
    in
    E.stub text
  in
object
  inherit foo obj
end
```

I'm declaring "stub" as external function returning 'a t where 'a is as direct or indirect subclass of foo. I'm using a local first class module to limit the exposure of that stub to inside the class bar so it can't be misused even if no .mli file is present.

Note: class bar must take an argument (here unit) or this doesn't type. Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: Why does bar need a dummy arg?